# Origen de la expresión "¿Está parida la gata?"

Tags: modismos, locuciones

La expresión **¿está parida la gata?** aparece en el [**DLE**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX) como

> 1. expr. desus. Era u. para indicar que había varias luces de sobra en una habitación.

El origen es sin duda antiguo, ya que aparece dos veces en el "Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales" de Correas de 1627:

> - Dízese kuando ai enzendidas más velas de las ke bastan, para ke se maten las ke sobran i no se gasten de balde. [pág.151]
> - Dizen esto kuando en kasa están enzendidas muchas luzes, para ke se apagen las ke sobran, i no se gasten las velas i azeite de balde. [pag 631]

Pero no he visto el origen, ni se me ocurre, la relación entre una [**gata parida**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX)

> 1. f. coloq. Persona flaca y extenuada.

y el exceso de luces encendidas. ¿Cuál puede ser ese origen?

Comment: Por decir lo primero que se me pasa por la cabeza, lo de "gata parida" puede no tener que ver con tu segunda expresión. Puede que sea simplemente que al parir la gata hiciera falta luz y calor para los gatitos y se encendieran velas de más como cosa excepcional.

Answer (score 4):

En el libro [La sabiduría de las naciones, o los evangelios abreviados](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=Pcw-AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) se puede encontrar para dicho refrán la siguiente explicación, que a su vez cita el *Tesoro de la lengua castellana* de Covarrubias:

> En el *Tesoro de la lengua castellana* se lee lo siguiente acerca de este modismo.
>   "Cuando hay muchas luces encendidas en la casa y todas casi juntas,
>   preguntamos si está parida la gata, porque de noche relucen mucho los
>   ojos de los gatos. Y estando la gata con sus gatillos, parece que
>   están ardiendo los ojos de todos como candilejas."

[image]

Como bien dice @Charlie en su comentario, la segunda expresión (Persona flaca y extenuada) no parece tener relación con la primera. Según lo que entiendo, hace referencia al estado de cansancio en que ha de quedar la gata despues del proceso de parto y se usa esta comparación para hablar del grado de extenuación el una persona.

Comment: Me han encantado tanto la explicación como la imagen que la ilustra. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @Mauricio Martinez he encontrado que la expresión aparece efectivamente en el diccionario de Covarrubias en dos artículos:

En **candil**:

> Quando estan muchos candiles encendidos por la casa, suele dezir el señor della, pareciendole que algunos se podian escusar: si esta parida la gata? Y este modo de reprehender las muchas luces, nacio de lo que escriuen los autores, y la experiencia nos muestra, que los ojos de los gatos relumbran de noche mucho, y quando la gata ha parido cinco o seys gatillos, ay muchos ojos relucientes, que parecen lumbres.

y en **gata**:

> Quando ay muchas luzes encendidas en la casa, y todas casi juntas; preguntamos si esta parida la gata, porque de noche reluzen mucho los ojos de los gatos. Y estando la gata con sus gatillos, parece que estan ardiendo los ojos de todos, como candelillas.

Sobre **gata parida**, Covarrubias indica en el mismo artículo:

> A la que està muy flaca dezimos, que està hecha vna gata parida, porque anda muy flaca dando leche a sus gatillos, y dexa de caçar por no apartarse
>   dellos, que aun el mesmo macho se los suele matar; como cuenta Aeliano libro 7. cap.40.

por lo que parece claro que las dos expresiones no están relacionadas, como indicaba @Charlie en el comentario a la pregunta.